# What icon to use for "Text Position"

Tags: icon

So my application can position text added inside an object for it to be inside, on top, on the bottom or left / right to the object.

Example:

[image]

So the options are to be hidden inside a button (which is represented with an icon). When the button is clicked it will show the options center, top, bottom, left and right.

What do you think the most suitable icon is to use on the button which says "Text Position"

Answer (score 2):

How about something along theses lines? (no pun intended)

[image]

Just a simple unambiguous way to show how the text can be aligned.